# How can I change the effect way on this jQuery iOS slider text?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to use this effect on my text but I need to change the way of effect. Is any change to change it? I attached a JSFiddle link to have a look

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/y6fpuyzd/`
```

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you want to do?

Comment: What did you mean by the way of effect!!!!

Comment: to change the way of effect. now it is going to right I need it to left

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think making the following change will achieve what you want. Please include more detail if its not correct.

```
setInterval(function() {
    gradient_percent -= speed;

    if (gradient_percent < gradient_offset.min) {
        gradient_percent = gradient_offset.max;
    }
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y6fpuyzd/1/).